# OpenVPN wont connect from android, TLS error

Tags: openvpn, tls, android

I have set up OpenVPN server and I am connecting it with no problem with my Fedora 23 computer using NetworkManager. Alas, when I try to connect from OpenVPN Connect application from Android, I get the server timeout. Loking at the server logs, this messge

> TLS Error: reading acknowledgement record from packet

Is the one that repeats around 50 times. and then after 60 seconds server declares timeout and gives up trying.

The Android Connect app on android uses OVPN file with embedded certificates while Network Manager in Linux uses three certificates I loaded manually.

EDIT --------

I managed to fix this issue by disabling TLS auth on server conf file. But I get another problem. The android device connects, but then I get this line in server logs

> IP packet with unknown IP version=15 seen

This line shows up indefinetely, whenever I try to access some site with android device. And browser in device says "server timed out". So I basically have no internet. On my Linux box, I connect without problem and have internet, so it is not IPtables masquarading issue (I had that issue too earlier, I fixed it)

Please some help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to fix this. Problem is that server and client configuration files have to have same settings. I first had TLS on one side but not on other, then second problem is that I had comp-lzo on one side but not on other. Linux is working over network manager because there I also trifled with configuration files, and I had this problem there to, but fixed it and forgot about it. So this one is fixed now.

Comment: The "comp-lzo" option was exactly the hint I needed! THANKS!